# How to turn flat list output into nested lists?

Tags: python, algorithm

This is my current code:

```
maximum = [
    [[0.352, 19, 'J'], [0.36, 19, 'J'], [0.627, 7, '7'], [0.412, 8, '8'], [0.258, 8, '8'], [0.317, 26, 'R'], [0.383, 20, 'K']], 
    [[0.389, 19, 'J'], [0.348, 19, 'J'], [0.499, 7, '7'], [0.369, 8, '8'], [0.365, 8, '8'], [0.289, 26, 'R'], [0.342, 20, 'K']],
    [[0.384, 19, 'J'], [0.387, 19, 'J'], [0.282, 7, '7'], [0.239, 8, '8'], [0.25, 8, '8'], [0.256, 26, 'R'], [0.357, 20, 'K']], 
    [[0.391, 19, 'J'], [0.379, 19, 'J'], [0.458, 7, '7'], [0.235, 8, '8'], [0.289, 8, '8'], [0.275, 26, 'R'], [0.378, 20, 'K']],
    [[0.401, 19, 'J'], [0.462, 7, '7'], [0.422, 19, 'J'], [0.287, 8, '8'], [0.271, 8, '8'], [0.286, 26, 'R'], [0.377, 20, 'K']],
    [[0.382, 19, 'J'], [0.35, 19, 'J'], [0.517, 7, '7'], [0.36, 8, '8'], [0.259, 8, '8'], [0.331, 26, 'R'], [0.36, 20, 'K']],
    [[0.391, 19, 'J'], [0.366, 19, 'J'], [0.299, 7, '7'], [0.234, 8, '8'], [0.269, 8, '8'], [0.239, 26, 'R'], [0.3, 20, 'K']]
]

letterslist = []
for max1 in maximum:
    for i in max1:
        x = i[2]
        letterslist.append(x)
print(letterslist)
```

My output:

```
['J', 'J', '7', '8', '8', 'R', 'K', 'J', 'J', '7', '8', '8', 'R', 'K', 'J', 'J', '7', '8', '8', 'R', 'K', 'J', 'J', '7', '8', '8', 'R', 'K', 'J', '7', 'J', '8', '8', 'R', 'K', 'J', 'J', '7', '8', '8', 'R', 'K', 'J', 'J', '7', '8', '8', 'R', 'K']
```

But I need to split my lists in the output, like

```
['J', 'J', '7', '8', '8', 'R', 'K'],
['J', 'J', '7', '8', '8', 'R', 'K'], 
['J', 'J', '7', '8', '8', 'R', 'K'], 
['J', 'J', '7', '8', '8', 'R', 'K',  ....etc.
```

How can I achieve this?

Comment: You can use a limited version of markdown to format your questions and answers quite nicely. [Here's some formatting help](https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This happens because you are appending individual values to `letterslist`, while you want to really get a list *of lists*. So that means you must append *lists* to `letterslist`.

To do that, you have to create those smaller lists first, add the values to it and then append that list to `letterlist`.

With minimal changes to your code, you could do it like this:

```
letterslist = []
for max1 in maximum:
    row = []
    for i in max1:
        x = i[2]
        row.append(x)
    letterslist.append(row)

print(letterslist)
```

In a more compact syntax, you would use *list comprehension*:

```
letterslist = [[trio[2] for trio in row] for row in maximum]
print(letterslist)
```